# How to migrate a specific MSO question from SO to MSO?

Tags: discussion, migration

The question [Should we call it C17 or C18?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748324/should-we-call-it-c17-or-c18) is a meta-question that belongs here on MSO rather than a question that belongs on SO.

- **How can we get the question migrated from SO to MSO?**

Normally, the process would be vote to close and select 'belongs on another site' and then nominate MSO as the other site (as pointed out by [pubsee2003](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/250725/psubsee2003) in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372474/how-to-migrate-a-specific-mso-question-from-so-to-mso?noredirect=1#comment620629_372474)).  However, as it stands, the question already has 4 close votes — 3 for 'primarily opinion-based' and 1 for 'other reason'.  Consequently, a VTC to migrate would lose out to the opinion-based majority.  Hence I believe this will require moderator intervention to migrate the question.

*A little background*

The content of the question is about the ISO/IEC 9899:2018 standard which was finalized in 2017 by the JTC1/SC22/WG14 committee, but published by ISO/IEC in 2018, with a 2018 date.

The question is primarily about the tags that should be used. This is non-trivial because there is already a [c18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c18) tag in use for a compiler known in some circles as C18 (44 questions).  There is a [c17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c17) tag in use for C17, as it was known in the later stages of development.  The version number of `__STDC_VERSION__` is `201710L`, justifying the 2017 moniker and the [c17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c17) tag.

Comment: How to migrate a question: you vote to close the question and select the migrate to MSO option.  And hope 2 other people agree with you

Comment: @psubsee2003: There are already 4 other close votes, and the majority is just for 'primarily opinion-based'.  And I do see that MSO is one of the options when you propose it is off-topic "belongs on another site" — it goes to show you how often I use that option in close-voting a question.  Since it is clear that 2 other people won't agree, my question still stands, though I'll update the question with some extra information.

Comment: What makes you think that question should be on MSO? I don't.

Comment: _"The question is primarily about the tags that should be used"_ The question doesn't mention tags even once.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not active in the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) world, so I'll risk the negative feedback from that  community to provide a general answer.

First, if you encounter a question you feel is appropriate for another site (including that site;s meta), the best option is to vote to close as "Off-topic > belongs on another site > " and select the more appropriate site.

At the time of this writing on that question there are 4 close votes and none are for migration, which means it is impossible to migrate it without a mod or a lot more work (reopening and reclosing). Just like any migration, you need 3 votes to migrate (4 on Stack Overflow).  So the solution is if you think this is a good topic for a meta question about tagging, then I'd suggest you ask it yourself on MSO.

---

But for this case, the OP is a 20K+ user and is active on MSO, so presumably would be aware what is on-topic on MSO, I'd be inclined to give them the benefit of doubt, especially since the question does not appear to be asking about tagging as you suggest. It may very well be off-topic on the main site, but I don't see it as being on-topic on meta.  So voting to close and downvoting would be the best option.

Answer (score 3):

The question was not intended to be a question about how we deal with it on SO. The SO usage part was kept separate from the question as a comment inside a parenthesis.

I was curious to know about canonical sources such as committee documents/internal names. I got such an answer from Jens Gustedt in the comments (I believe he is a member of the committee). `__STDC_VERSION__` is the most canonical source and also consistent with C95, C99 and C11 (it was not part of C89/C90), so that constant should reflect the informal name "C17".

(Less importantly, C17 is the term used by gcc, and C's bastard brother C++ was revised at the same time, named C++17.)

After this, I updated the various tag wikis affected: [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c11) and [c17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c17), to mention the relevant `__STDC_VERSION__`.

The question need not be migrated to meta. We can close it or delete it if it holds no value.